# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function (redux)

Tags: redux

I am having a TypeError (TypeError: Object(...) is not a function) when I want to dispatch an action. I'm not using any middleware and don't know what I can do to solve it. I had this error already yesterday but somehow managed to solve it (i donk know how i did this)

This is the App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { store } from "../store";
import { withdrawMoney} from "../actions";

const App = () => {
return (
  <div className="app">
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-header">
        Welcome to your bank account
      </div>
      <div className="card-body">
        <h1>Hello, {store.getState().name}!</h1>
        <ul className="list-group">
          <li className="list-group-item">
            <h4>Your total amount:</h4>
            {store.getState().balance}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button className="btn btn-primary card-link" data-amount="5000" onClick={dispatchBtnAction}>Withdraw $5,000</button>
        <button className="btn btn-primary card-link" data-amount="10000" onClick={dispatchBtnAction}>Witdhraw $10,000</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}

function dispatchBtnAction(e) {
  store.dispatch(withdrawMoney(e.target.dataset.amount));
}

export default App;
```

Here is the actioncreator:

```
function withdrawMoney(amount) {
  return {
    type: "ADD_TODO",
    amount
  }
}
```

If you need here is the reducer:

```
export default (state, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  return state
}
```

As you can see I'm a very new to redux but I'd like to know what mistake I make all the time when dispatching an action. Thanks

Comment: For me, it is wrong to import of connect. I had imported connect from mongoose(auto-import extension cause this problem)

Comment: I would recommend just moving away from Global Stores and Redux and use Context API with Hooks, instead. Context and Hooks will do everything Redux does and more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you aren't exporting the withdrawMoney function, so you aren't able to call it in the component that you're attempting to import into.

try:

```
export function withdrawMoney(amount) {
  return {
    type: "ADD_TODO",
    amount
  }
}
```

Comment: a message from future: you are legend! after a four hours work, i desperately started for looking answers on internet. and finally came here. after simplicity of the solution, i've wondered that how dumb should i become more. a mulatto, an albino, a mosquito and one thousand kisses deep!

Answer (score 11):

Another subtle mistake that will cause this error is what I tried to do, don't accidentally do this:

```
import React, { useSelector, useState ... } from 'react'
```

it should be:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
```

Comment: Why there is a valid useSelector that you can import from React as well? This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! I feel so stupid lol!!! Can't believe I wasted a whole 12 hours for this.

Comment: Thanks Alex, saved me a huge headache with this!

Comment: I did this too. I'm turning in my dev tools. lol

Answer (score 2):

Try to install :
npm i react@next react-dom@next  and run again

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
Bank: state.Bank,
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {
  dispatch,    
  ...bindActionCreators({ getBanks, addBank }, dispatch)
  }
 }

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BankComponent);
```

this worked like a Charm for me .

Answer (score 1):

bit Late to party,
to me it was about **casing.**

```
export const addTodo = text => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  desc: text
});
export const removeTodo = id=> ({
  type: REMOVE_TODO,
  id: id
})  
export const increaseCount = () => ({
  type: INCREASE_COUNT
});
export const decreaseCount = () => ({
  type: DECREASE_COUNT
})
```

when I renamed all those like

```
export const AddTodo = text => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  desc: text
});
export const RemoveTodo = id => ({
  type: REMOVE_TODO,
  id: id
})  
export const IncreaseCount = () => ({
  type: INCREASE_COUNT
});
export const DecreaseCount = () => ({
  type: DECREASE_COUNT
})
```

it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours debugging this, turns out I was doing this:

`import React, { connect } from "react";`

Instead of

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
```

It's weird the former didn't throw an error, but it will cause the problem!

Comment: this was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

First problem I see right off the bat is your reducer is not setup to do anything with the dispatched `withdrawMoney` action creator.

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO": {
      return {
        ...state,
        amount: action.amount,
    };
  }
  default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

If this does not help, the code from your other files would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the main issue, but it looks like you're not using the React-Redux library to work with the store.  You *can* reference the store directly in your React components, but it's a bad practice.  See [my explanation for why you should be using React-Redux instead of writing "manual" store handling logic](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/6hperk/i_use_react_and_redux_but_never_reactredux_what/dj0fywb/).

Answer (score 0):

After updating `react-redux` to version 7.2.0+ I was receiving this error anytime I wrote:

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

I stopped my application and re-ran it with npm start, and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I was using redux toolkit and for me the problem was an extra '}'
such that my 'reducers' object, in 'createSlice' function, already had a closing curly brace before my second reducer
and my 2nd reducer was actually outside the 'reducers' object,
making it not a reducer and hence not working even when you export or import it properly.

So the problem is not in your export or import, but actually where your function is defined.
This may be different for other users, but in my case this turned out to be the cause of this error.